# Make jQuery MeanMenu start expanded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jQuery so I'm still struggling at easier things. I am using MeanMenu plugin (https://github.com/meanthemes/meanMenu) to make a responsive menu, but I want this menu to start expanded instead of collapsed and I don't know how.

There is no option at the defaults to start with the menu in expanded mode.
Already tried tweaking the css classes but it doesnt work appropiately.
If someone could give me hint in the right direction it would be really appreciated.

---

Answer to this question was to change line 179 at mainmenu.js from `jQuery('.mean-nav ul').hide();` to `jQuery('.mean-nav ul').show();`

Comment: **`meanShowChildren:true`**: true to show children in the menu, false to hide them

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that only works to show or hide child elements from the ul, and I wanted whole <ul> tag to be displayed. I finally solved by changing the line 179 at meanmenu.js from `jQuery('.mean-nav ul').hide();` to `jQuery('.mean-nav ul').show();` Now it looks pretty obvious but when you are new to a language it's not so obvious :D